# What viewer for mzML data should I use under Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I want to open .mzML files containing mass spectrometer data under Ubuntu 18.04. Which tool would you recommend for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite happy with [mmass](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mmass):

```
$ sudo apt-get install mmass
```